# In matlab, how to concatenate value calculated in a for loop?

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, concatenation

In matlab, if I have a code that calculates the rate of something in a for loop like this

```
for t=1:10
Ratek=(1/2)*(log2(1+SINR1k)+log2(1+SINR2k));
end
```

and each time the value of the rate differs, I want in to concatenate all the values of this rate in each loop so that after the 10th loop I have the 10 rates calculated to use them. How can I do this ?

Comment: What's changing in your loop? Are `SINR1k` and `SINR2k` scalars or 1x10 vectors? If nothing is changing, `Ratek(1:10) = (1/2)*(log2(1+SINR1k)+log2(1+SINR2k));` would be simplest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this, building on @Joachim's answer:

```
Ratek = []
for t=1:10
    val = (1/2)*(log2(1+SINR1k)+log2(1+SINR2k));
    if ~Any(Ratek == val)
        Ratek(end+1) = val;
end
```

If you want to contenate as string:

```
num2str(Ratek)
```

I'm not really into MATLAB, but that's my take.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to concatenate the calculation result to a vector; you can then assign to `Ratek(end+1)` to append the value;

```
Ratek = []
for t=1:10
  Ratek(end+1) = (1/2)*(log2(1+SINR1k)+log2(1+SINR2k));
end
```

(assuming the real calculation gives a separate value each time instead of the static example)

As a side note, growing vectors and loops may really hurt performance if you do it frequently, so be aware of the performance implications.

Answer (score 1):

If your data is static and you only want do duplicate the same result 10 times, then

```
Ratek(1:10) = (1/2)*(log2(1 + SINR1k)+log2(1 + SINR2k));
```

But, that would not be of much use, so I'm going to assume that `SINR1k` and `SINR2k` are 10x1 vectors.

```
SINR1k = randi(10,10,1);
SINR2k = randi(10,10,1);
```

Now, you *could* do:

```
Ratek = zeros(10,1); %// Important to preallocate memory to avoid growing vectors inside loops

for t=1:10
   Ratek(t) = (1/2)*(log2(1 + SINR1k(t))+log2(1 + SINR2k(t)));
end
```

This is a much better approach than starting with an empty matrix and adding new elements to it. However, in MATLAB loops can be avoided in cases like this, so the following line will give the same result as the loop above:

```
Ratek = (1/2) * (log2(1 + SINR1k)+log2(1 + SINR2k));
```

## Benchmarking:

```
n = 100;   %// A bit bigger datasample
SINR1k = randi(100,n,1);  %// Random numbers
SINR2k = randi(100,n,1);  %// Random numbers

%//Approach 1, growing vectors:
tic
for ii = 1:1000   %// Several runs to account for warm-up etc.
  Ratek = [];
  for t=1:n
    Ratek(end+1) = (1/2)*(log2(1+SINR1k(t))+log2(1+SINR2k(t)));
  end
end
toc
Elapsed time is 0.291688 seconds.

%// Approach 2, pre-allocation:
tic
for ii = 1:1000   %// Several runs to account for warm-up etc.
  Ratek = zeros(n,1);
  for t=1:n
    Ratek(t) = (1/2)*(log2(1+SINR1k(t))+log2(1+SINR2k(t)));
  end
end
toc
Elapsed time is 0.070791 seconds.

%// Approach 3, vectorization:
tic
for ii = 1:1000
    Ratek = (1/2)*(log2(1+SINR1k)+log2(1+SINR2k));
end
toc
Elapsed time is 0.056612 seconds.
```

As the benchmark results above show, preallocation makes it more than 4 times as fast whereas vectorization improves performance even more.

If you actually only want to duplicate the results:

```
tic
for ii = 1:1000
    Ratek(1:n) = (1/2)*(log2(4)+log2(5));
end
toc
Elapsed time is 0.010811 seconds.
```